# How to generate consecutive unique ids for successive data frame's column generated across successive runs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scd2

I'm working on SCDTYPE2 in spark Scala,so my code will create new data frame every day and i need to know how to stamp with new unique ids whenever i create my data frame everyday

I have tried `monotonically_increasing_id()` function to create unique id. but its generating unique id in each data frame. but its not unique for each runs.Its repeat the same unique id again for each run.

Also I have tried to create unique id using timestamp column in my data frame along with `monotonically_increasing_id` but it giving output in double datatype and i have convert back to integer/string but its rounding of the id and generating duplicate Ids.

```
 val DF2 =DF1.withColumn("key1",((date_format(col("date_column"), "ddmmyy")*24*60+ date_format(col("date_column"), "HHmmss")*60 + monotonically_increasing_id())*(-1)).cast(IntegerType)).withColumn("key2",$"key1".cast(StringType)).withColumn("date1",(date_format(col("date_column"), "ddmmyy")*24*60)).withColumn("date2",(date_format(col("date_column"), "HHmmss")*60 )).withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id()*(-1)).select($"date_column",$"date1",$"date2",$"id",$"key1",$"key2")
```

I expect unique id should be generated  irrespective of the generation the data frame. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: scd2 is dwh dimension?

Comment: Complicated, see my answer for a holistic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `uuid` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

You can use `uuid.uuid4()` for a completely random id. Or `uuid.uudi1()` for a more intricate sequantial id.

Comment: can you help me  with spark scala? . Am not using python

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I gave to this question [How to implement Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD2) Type 2 in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark/54066697#54066697)

This addresses it all and you can see the answer to your question as well.