# Implement SCD Type 2 in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to implement SCD Type 2 logic in Spark 2.4.4. I've two Data Frames; one containing 'Existing Data' and the other containing 'New Incoming Data'.

Input and expected output are given below. What needs to happen is:

1. All incoming rows should get appended to the existing data.
2. Only following 3 rows which were previously 'active' should become inactive with appropriate 'endDate' populated as follows:

   pk=1, amount = 20  => Row should become 'inactive' & 'endDate' is the 'startDate' of following row (Lead)

   pk=2, amount = 100 => Row should become 'inactive' & 'endDate' is the 'startDate' of following row (Lead)

   pk=3, amount = 750 => Row should become 'inactive' & 'endDate' is the 'startDate' of following row (Lead)

How do I do this in Spark?

**Existing Data:**

```
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
| pk|amount|          startDate|            endDate|active|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|  1|    10|2019-01-01 12:00:00|2019-01-20 05:00:00|     0|
|  1|    20|2019-01-20 05:00:00|               null|     1|
|  2|   100|2019-01-01 00:00:00|               null|     1|
|  3|    75|2019-01-01 06:00:00|2019-01-26 08:00:00|     0|
|  3|   750|2019-01-26 08:00:00|               null|     1|
| 10|    40|2019-01-01 00:00:00|               null|     1|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

**New Incoming Data:**

```
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
| pk|amount|          startDate|            endDate|active|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|  1|    50|2019-02-01 07:00:00|2019-02-02 08:00:00|     0|
|  1|    75|2019-02-02 08:00:00|               null|     1|
|  2|   200|2019-02-01 05:00:00|2019-02-01 13:00:00|     0|
|  2|    60|2019-02-01 13:00:00|2019-02-01 19:00:00|     0|
|  2|   500|2019-02-01 19:00:00|               null|     1|
|  3|   175|2019-02-01 00:00:00|               null|     1|
|  4|    50|2019-02-02 12:00:00|2019-02-02 14:00:00|     0|
|  4|   300|2019-02-02 14:00:00|               null|     1|
|  5|   500|2019-02-02 00:00:00|               null|     1|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
| pk|amount|          startDate|            endDate|active|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|  1|    10|2019-01-01 12:00:00|2019-01-20 05:00:00|     0|
|  1|    20|2019-01-20 05:00:00|2019-02-01 07:00:00|     0|
|  1|    50|2019-02-01 07:00:00|2019-02-02 08:00:00|     0|
|  1|    75|2019-02-02 08:00:00|               null|     1|
|  2|   100|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-02-01 05:00:00|     0|
|  2|   200|2019-02-01 05:00:00|2019-02-01 13:00:00|     0|
|  2|    60|2019-02-01 13:00:00|2019-02-01 19:00:00|     0|
|  2|   500|2019-02-01 19:00:00|               null|     1|
|  3|    75|2019-01-01 06:00:00|2019-01-26 08:00:00|     0|
|  3|   750|2019-01-26 08:00:00|2019-02-01 00:00:00|     1|
|  3|   175|2019-02-01 00:00:00|               null|     1|
|  4|    50|2019-02-02 12:00:00|2019-02-02 14:00:00|     0|
|  4|   300|2019-02-02 14:00:00|               null|     1|
|  5|   500|2019-02-02 00:00:00|               null|     1|
| 10|    40|2019-01-01 00:00:00|               null|     1|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Wondering why I got a down vote (-1) on this question. Can someone explain please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark/54066697#54066697 where I answered the question. Worked better with KUDU but we did this with re-stating and the small files issue can be compacted in various manners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by selecting the first `startDate` for each group `pk` from the new DataFrame and join with the old one to update the desired columns.
Then, you can union all the join result and the new DataFrame.

Something like this:

```
// get first state by date for each pk group
val w = Window.partitionBy($"pk").orderBy($"startDate")
val updates = df_new.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).filter("rn = 1").select($"pk", $"startDate")

// join with old data and update old values when there is match
val joinOldNew = df_old.join(updates.alias("new"), Seq("pk"), "left")
                       .withColumn("endDate", when($"endDate".isNull && $"active" === lit(1) && $"new.startDate".isNotNull, $"new.startDate").otherwise($"endDate"))
                       .withColumn("active", when($"endDate".isNull && $"active" === lit(1) && $"new.startDate".isNotNull, lit(0)).otherwise($"active"))
                       .drop($"new.startDate")

// union all
val result = joinOldNew.unionAll(df_new)
```

Comment: This looks promising but I am getting this message: "otherwise() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when()". I have this...

.withColumn("endDate", when(col("endDate").isNull
                && col("active") === lit(1) && col("new.startDate").isNotNull,
                col("new.startDate").otherwise(col("endDate"))))

Comment: You're missing some brackets there... as you're calling `.otherwise` on `col("new.startDate")` instead of the `when` column.

Comment: My bad. Fixed missing brackets. It's working but I had change logic for 'active' column as follows:             
<code>
.withColumn("active", when(col("endDate").isNull, lit(1))
                .otherwise(lit(0)))
</code>
It seems the 'withColumn' for 'endDate' changes value of that column so when the control comes to 'withColumn' for 'active' endDate is already changed!

Answer (score 1):

1. Union 2 data frames
2. `groupByKey` on pk
3. `mapGroups` will provide a tuple of key and iterator of rows.
4. On each group, sort rows, iterate over all rows, close records you want and keep the rows you want.

```
   val df = //read your df containing 
   df.groupByKey( row => (row.getAs[String]("pk")))
     .mapGroups( case (key, rows) => 
     // apply all logic you need to apply per PK. 
     //sort rows by date, survive the latest, close the old )
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the 'Groups' that didn't get updated (e.g. pk = 10) will unnecessarily get processed. When 'existing' data is BIG (over 100 million rows) this will have significant impact. After 'Union', all we really need to do in this case is update 3 rows! Need a better way. Thanks.

Comment: I thought I am getting you started and then you can tune from there. If the dataset is big then you join them in pk and filter based on active and date comparisons. Then union the result with the other part which didn’t need processing

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to answer suggested by @blackbishop I was able to get it working. Here's the working version (in case someone's interested):

```
    // get first state by date for each pk group
    val w = Window.partitionBy("pk").orderBy("startDate")
    val updates = dfNew.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).filter("rn = 1").select("pk", "startDate")

    // join with old data and update old values when there is match
    val joinOldNew = dfOld.join(updates.alias("new"), Seq("pk"), "left")
        .withColumn("endDate", when(col("endDate").isNull
            && col("active") === lit(1) && col("new.startDate").isNotNull,
            col("new.startDate")).otherwise(col("endDate")))
        .withColumn("active", when(col("endDate").isNull, lit(1))
            .otherwise(lit(0)))
        .drop(col("new.startDate"))


    // union all (Order By is not necessary! Added to facilitate testing.)
    val results = joinOldNew.union(dfNew).orderBy(col("pk"), col("startDate"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a Delta Lake option for the above problem, refer the code linked below.

https://github.com/EndrisKerga/Spark-Slow-Changing-Dimensions-Type-2-Demo/blob/master/SCDType2.scala