# How to avoid OutOfMemory in Apache Spark when creating a row_number column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory, row-number

I am developing some transformations in an ETL (using Spark SQL) where one of them, in particular, creates a row_number in a certain dataframe like this:

`ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (order by column_x)`

This first issues the following warning:

`WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.`

Which eventually leads to an OutOfMemory error. Because there needs to be one single row_number ordering, from top to bottom, using some partition is out of the question, so I believe the only thing I can do about this is to somehow write the dataframe to disk by using some partitioning, re-reading it from disk as separate dataframes, create a row_number for each of them and then union them in the right order.

Is my reasoning correct? How to proceed, either if I am right or wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: "create a row_number for each of them and then union them in the right order." won't there be several datasets numbered from 1 to n in this case? If yes, after union you are going to end up with few records with same row_numbers. Do you need this row_number to be consecutive within whole dataset? If not, you can try to use monotonically_increasing_id function

Comment: Could you share `column_x` data type (and possibly what type of values it stores)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `delta` feature, it is recent. E.g.:

```
create table T1 (
     id long GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
     c1 string,
     ...
)
```

If you have small sets of data to run, by running more frequently, then there should be no issue with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

You do not state if re-state or incremental, but here is an approach: [How to implement Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD2) Type 2 in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark/54066697#54066697)