# I need help applying SCD 2 with this Azure Synapse Python code that merges a dataframe to a Delta Table

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I’m trying to express an SCD Type 2 in my dimension table using python in an Azure Synapse Notebook. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
(
existing_table.alias(“old”)
   .merge(
       new_table.alias(“new”),
       “old.keycol = new.keycol”
   )
   .whenMatchedUpdate(condition = “old.CurrentRecord = true AND old.Rate <> new.rate”
       ,set = {“old.RecordEndDate” : “new.RecordStartDate”
              ,”old.CurrentRecord” : “false”
              }
       )
   .whenNotMatchedInsert(values = {“old.surrogatekey” : max(“old.surrogatekey”)+1
                                  ,”old.keycol” : “new.keycol”
                                  ,”old.Rate” : “new.Rate”
                                  ,”old.RecordStartDate” : “new.RecorStartDate”
                                  ,”old.CurrentRecord” : “true”
                                  }
       )
   .execute()

 )
```

I’m getting an error that says:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve old.surrogatekey in INSERT clause given colums new.keycol, new.Rate, new.RecordStartDate
```

What I’m trying to do is to reference the ***keycol*** column from the table ***existing_table***. I want to get the maximum value from ***keycol***, add 1 then use the resulting value as the input value for the merge.

I’m new to all of this and I would really appreciate any help I could get to get this done. Thank you so much.

Comment: Look a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark-using-sql-joi/54066697#54066697 Two variants

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code to perfrom **SCD Type 2** behavior by keeping track of historical changes to the dimension data and assigning unique key values to new records.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, current_date
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SCDType2Example").getOrCreate()
existing_data = [
    (1, "John Doe", "2023-10-01", "9999-12-31"),
    (2, "Jane Smith", "2023-09-15", "9999-12-31"),
]
existing_schema = ["keycol", "name", "valid_from", "valid_to"]
existing_df = spark.createDataFrame(existing_data, schema=existing_schema)
new_data = [
    ("John Doe", "2023-10-09"),
    ("Jane Smith", "2023-10-09"),
]
new_schema = ["name", "valid_from"]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_data, schema=new_schema)
max_keycol = existing_df.agg({"keycol": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
next_keycol = max_keycol + 1 if max_keycol is not None else 1
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(F.col("valid_from").desc())
ranked_df = existing_df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(window_spec))
updated_existing_df = ranked_df.withColumn("valid_to", lit("2023-10-08")).where(col("row_number") == 1).drop("row_number")
new_df = new_df.withColumn("keycol", lit(next_keycol))
next_keycol += 1 
new_df = new_df.withColumn("valid_to", lit("9999-12-31"))
updated_dim_table = updated_existing_df.union(new_df.select(existing_schema))
updated_dim_table.show()
```

[image]

- In the above code finding the maximum value of the "**keycol** column in the **existing_df** using the `agg` function. If there are existing records, it will calculate the next available key value by adding **1**; otherwise, it will set it to **1.**
- I have created a window specification `window_spec` for ranking rows within **existing_df** based on the "**valid_from**" column in descending order.
- This is used to identify the latest records for each "**name**."
- Rank rows within **existing_df** using `row_number()` over the specified window, and add a "**row_number**" column to the DataFrame.
- Update the "**valid_to**" date for the existing latest records (those with "row_number" equal to 1) to "2023-10-08" to mark them as not current anymore.
- Assign unique key values to the new data by adding the next available key value to the "**keycol**" column.
- Set the "**valid_to**" date for the new records to "**9999-12-31**" to indicate that they are the current records with no expiration date.
- Union the updated existing data and the new data into a single
  DataFrame **updated_dim_table**.